# eclipse probleam installing more plugins

Tags: eclipse-plugin, flexbuilder

i am getting this error

```
Unexpected error encountered while preparing for the operation. 
org.eclipse.core.runtime.AssertionFailException
```

and in the detail window

```
Unexpected error encountered while preparing for the operation.
null argument:
```

when i am try to update from this site 
http://mantis.faratasystems.com/downloads/update/site.xml

i am running eclipse 3.4.1 and flex builder as a plugin 
how can i correct this error and install this plugin (Fx2Ant)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For me, the new plugin installer "p2" gets often into an inconsistent state. My solution is to have three Eclipse installs: A work installation, a template and one "install". When I need to install some plugin, I delete the "install", copy it fresh from "template" and then do the install in there.

After the install, I copy the new files under "plugins" and "features" to my work installation into the directory `eclipse/dropins/` + name of the plugin. See [my blog](http://blog.pdark.de/2008/09/29/installing-eclipse-341-despite-p2/) for details.

Comment: not sound so great but i am new in eclipse 
maybe this is the way to go??

Comment: Yeah, sorry. IMHO, p2 was really not mature enough when it was spread all over the world.

Answer (score 1):

Helpful as @Aaron's suggestion is, it is a bit tedious. I tried it out. In my case the copied plugins just wouldn't show up in the UI. Correcting the file permissions didn't help either and I gave up. Frustrated, I looked around for other resolutions to this bug and found one on the Eclipse wiki that can help you replace p2 with the original Update manager in Ganymede. I tried it out and it works. There is also an automated script available for download that does the same. I think this is a good solution till the issues with p2 get resolved.

You can read more about how to do this [here](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Equinox_p2_Removal).

Note: Works only for 3.4.x. It says that it will not work with 3.5 since p2 is tightly coupled with other components of 3.5.